# Hibernate parent-child relationship update

Tags: hibernate, parent-child, hibernate-mapping, self-join, self-reference

Dear Hibernate experts!

I've faced with some interesting case to my opinion.
I have such a self-relation mapped:

[image]

I try to create `Category` object and set a collection of sub categories via `setCategories(List<Category> categories)` method. Nothing happens from perspective of sub categories - they aren't stored in a database. But when I add them one by one using `addSubCategory(Category subCategory)` method everything works as it has to work. I know it is due to the fact that I explicitly set a parent for a sub category.

The question is - can I configure this mapping somehow that the parent for subcategory is updated automatically?

Comment: Please cut and paste code, don't use an image.